# magento 1.9 switch theme on checkout page

Tags: layout, themes, magento-1.9

i want to switch theme on checkout page and cart page , i am developing custom Checkout page to work with default RWD theme ? i want to change theme to default rwd theme on checkout and cart page

Answer (score 0):

I think just copy the files from the base theme to the RWD theme and edit the files in the RWD theme

Comment: copying files from RWD theme to my custom theme ? how it will check theme on checkout page ?

Comment: You need to enable path hind to know exactly the files and paths. If it does not exist in RWD, you just copy them from Base theme.

Comment: I think you don,t understand my Question, i am using custom theme right now every thing is fine , i just want to switch RWD theme on checkout page hope its clear now

Comment: You need to temporarily convert the theme to RWD.
On the checkout page of RWD, you will see the css and js paths needed. Please copy them to use for custom theme. After switching to custom theme, you use the css and js files from RWD theme to replace the js and css on your custom theme.

Comment: Also, do not forget to update the xml and phtml files of the checkout from RWD to your custom theme